# class has no attribute, even with self given as a parameter - Python

Tags: python

I have the following `Python` class:

```
import sys
import re

class Parser:

    def __init__(self, filename=""):
        self.filename = filename

    def parse(self):

        try:
            table = {}
            fp = open(self.filename, 'r')
            records = fp.readlines()
            for record in records:
                (index, column, value) = record.strip().split()
                value = value[:3]
                table[column] = value

            return table

        except IOError:
            print "Could not open file ", self.filename
            sys.exit(1) 

    def organize_map(self, table={}):

        new_table = {
            'profile_1': [],
            'profile_2': [],
            'profile_3': [],
            'profile_4': []
        }

        for k, v in table.iteritems():

            if re.match("profile1", k):
                new_table['profile_1'].append(int(v))
            elif re.match("profile2", k):
                new_table['profile_2'].append(int(v))
            elif re.match("profile3", k):
                new_table['profile_3'].append(int(v))
            elif re.match("profile4", k):
                new_table['profile_4'].append(int(v)) 


        for k, v in new_table.iteritems():
            v.sort()
            v = v[2:len(v)-2]
            new_table[k] = v
            new_table[k].append(avg(v))
            new_table[k].append(std(v))

        return new_table

parser = Parser()
table = parser.parse()
print parser.organize_map(table)
```

when i execute the `parser.py` file, I get:

```
  File "parser.py", line 94, in <module>
    print parser.organize_map(table)
AttributeError: Parser instance has no attribute 'organize_map'
```

I don't know why ... I defined `organized_map()` with the `self` keyword ... any idea?
A sample file:

```
1: profile1_test_1 155700802.32
2: profile1_test_2 156129130.88
3: profile1_test_3 155961744.64
4: profile1_test_4 155917583.6
5: profile1_test_5 156193748.16
6: profile1_test_6 155749778.88
7: profile1_test_7 156040104.72
8: profile1_test_8 156934277.68
9: profile1_test_9 156976866.56
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: It should rather say `Could not open file ` and quit, which it does for me.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I give the filename though ... I changed it because the file is hardcoded into the class for now ...

Comment: @LevLevitsky I've added a sample file

Comment: It now says `NameError: global name 'avg' is not defined` which is inside `organized_map`, so it is called. Are you sure it's not a tab/space problem as suggested below?

Comment: Sorry I posted a stupid answer, but definitely your question lacks information. You probably stripped too much code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mix indentation with tabs and spaces in your source code, probably the python interpreter does interpret the tabs differently than you expect. The definition of `organize_map` is indented with tabs, most likely it ends up to be seen as a local function inside of `parse`.

Don't mix indentation with tabs and spaces, it only leads to confusion. You can also use Python's `-t` parameter when running the script to get warnings about inconsistent indentations:

```
python -t myscript.py
```

Comment: same error ... using the `-t` param didn't change anything. The problem is different text editors

Comment: I copy/pasted the code from the question into a new window in IDLE and it worked.

Comment: I think you've got prob indentation issues